# Gradle plugin 3.0 rewrite versionName

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I migrated to Android studio 3 and using gradle plugin v3.0.0-beta6. I would like to rewrite versionName/vesionCode of output .apk files. 
I used following code for gradle plugin 2.x in the build.gradle of my Android app module

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    def flavor = variant.mergedFlavor

    flavor.versionName="${VERSION_NAME}"
    if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
        flavor.versionCode=9999
    } else {
        flavor.versionCode=Integer.parseInt(gitCommitCount)
    }
}
```

It doesn't work on gradle plugin v3.0.0-beta6. For versionCode, I successfully rewrite it with the solution in this [Gradle 3.0.0 alpha variant output issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45159978/gradle-3-0-0-alpha-variant-output-issue)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the ApkVariantOutput.setVersionCodeOverride method. Just like the following:

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.name == "release") {
        variant.outputs.all {
            setVersionCodeOverride(project.VERSION_CODE.toInteger())
            setVersionNameOverride(project.VERSION_NAME)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `setVersionNameOverride()` updates only in the AndroidManifest and not in the BuildConfig file

Comment: @SankarV Did you ever figure out how to update it in the BuildConfig file?

Comment: @Squeazer I set it in the default config itself. I have a method with a parameter and based on the parameter (debug/release) it will return the right version name. I change the parameter manually whenever i generate a release build